# SimpleDateFormat is not adding IST timezone offset

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to correct a date with some offset value according to the time zone. So, when I format a timestamp with a time zone offset, I expected that SimpleDateFormat will add the offset value to the time.
Here is what I tried:

```
package com.krishna.mytrials;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DateExperiments {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        //Date we set in UI
        Date today = new Date();
        //The long value
        String todayBrowserLocalTimeStamp = sdf.format(today);
        System.out.println(todayBrowserLocalTimeStamp);
        Date todayBrowserLocalTimeStampDate = sdf.parse(todayBrowserLocalTimeStamp);
        System.out.println("Today's browser local time stamp: " + todayBrowserLocalTimeStampDate);
        System.out.println("And its long value:" + todayBrowserLocalTimeStampDate.getTime());
        System.out.println("Date generate from long:"+ new Date(todayBrowserLocalTimeStampDate.getTime()));
        //What server does to the above mid night time stamp of browser-local time zone
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        //What we get after it applied the server time zone to browser-local date
        //### This is the wrong date
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat();
        sdf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        sdf2.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        System.out.println(sdf2.format(todayBrowserLocalTimeStampDate));
        String utcDateString = sdf.format(todayBrowserLocalTimeStampDate);
        System.out.println("The above mid night time stamp of browser-local time zone"
                + "is converted to GMT.### The wrong one:");
        System.out.println(utcDateString);
        //### The wrong date constructed
        Date utcDate = sdf.parse(utcDateString);
        System.out.println("###Wrong date:"+utcDate);
        //### The wrong long
        Long utcLong = utcDate.getTime();
        System.out.println("###Wrong long:"+utcLong);
        // What we will do with the GMT+05:30
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));
        String dateToBeCorrected = sdf2.format(todayBrowserLocalTimeStampDate);
        System.out.println("Date to be corrected:"+ dateToBeCorrected);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        Date correctedDate = sdf3.parse(dateToBeCorrected);
        System.out.println(correctedDate);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf4 = new SimpleDateFormat();
        sdf4.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
        String correctedString = sdf4.format(correctedDate);
        System.out.println("Corrected date:" + formatDateToString(correctedDate,"dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a", "IST"));


    }

    public static String formatDateToString(Date date, String format,
            String timeZone) {
        // null check
        if (date == null) return null;
        // create SimpleDateFormat object with input format
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        // default system timezone if passed null or empty
        if (timeZone == null || "".equalsIgnoreCase(timeZone.trim())) {
            timeZone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID();
        }
        // set timezone to SimpleDateFormat
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
        // return Date in required format with timezone as String
        return sdf.format(date);
    }


}
Here is the output:
2017-01-12
Today's browser local time stamp: Thu Jan 12 00:00:00 IST 2017
And its long value:1484159400000
Date generate from long:Thu Jan 12 00:00:00 IST 2017
2017-01-11 18:30
The above mid night time stamp of browser-local time zoneis converted to GMT.### The wrong one:
2017-01-11
###Wrong date:Wed Jan 11 05:30:00 IST 2017
###Wrong long:1484092800000
Date to be corrected:2017-01-11 18:30
Wed Jan 11 18:30:00 IST 2017
Corrected date:11 Jan 2017 06:30:00 PM
It is supposed add 05:30. to the date. What am I doing wrong?
```

Comment: Your snippet is way too convoluted. Please trim it to the essentials.

Comment: Yeah, update the question and show only the code that is giving problem.

Comment: Also, please separate sub-tasks inside a method with a single blank line.  It makes things considerably more readable.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to consider that roundtrips using formatting and parsing can loose informations.** This is due to the fact that a formatted date might contain less informations than the original `Date`-instance had. Look at this data loss:

Original timestamp (variable `todayBrowserLocalTimeStampDate`) was: `2017-01-11 18:30` (in UTC) or as long: `1484175600000L`

```
String utcDateString = sdf.format(new Date(1484175600000L));
// 2017-01-11
Date utcDate = sdf.parse(utcDateString);
```

**Here you strip away the time part AND parse the stripped string again.** Of course, the resulting new `Date`-instance must loose the corresponding time part, too, and cannot be the same as before.

`2017-01-11` (with zero time) would be rendered in your IST-zone 5:30 hours later, that is: 2017-01-11T05:30+05:30 (remember: `Date.toString()` uses your IST-zone assuming that is your system zone). This is same instant as 2017-01-11T00:00Z. All is fine, only your expectation expressed in line indicated by prefix `###Wrong date` is wrong.